# Create cron as a apache user and run as root user

Tags: cron, apache-httpd, root, services

I am creating this cron as apache user and want to run this cron as root, below is my code snippet:

```
# Create a cron job to restart apache
cron_file="/etc/cron.d/restart_apache_crontab"
cron_job="*/1 * * * * root condrestart-apache.sh"
echo "$cron_job" > $cron_file
chmod 777 $cron_file
exit 0
```

Provided sufficient privileges to cron.d directory (changes directory group to apache user) and script generated a 
cron file restart_apache_crontab at /etc/cron.d/ using the above script

condrestart-apache.sh contains below code and has sufficient access permissions for apache user:

```
rm -f /etc/cron.d/restart_apache_crontab
/sbin/service httpd restart > restart-apache.log
```

This will first remove cron and then restart apache (means cron will run only for 1 time)

I am able to create cron as apache user but not able to execute it as root user.

Please help me on this.. code snippet will be really helpful..

Comment: Why not just run the cronjob as root ? Do you not have access to run as root ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the cronjob `"*/1 * * * * root condrestart-apache.sh"` I would expect an absolute path to your restart script e.g. `/usr/local/sbin/condrestart-apache.sh`.

And  condrestart-apache.sh must be an executable (e.g. `chmod 755`) shell script and of course include something like `#!/bin/sh`  which is missing from your snippet.

The primary reason to restart Apache would be to effect a configuration change, so checking if the syntax is correct before trying to restart your webserver and killing it may be a good idea as well...

```
#!/bin/sh
# /usr/local/sbin/condrestart-apache.sh
rm -f /etc/cron.d/restart_apache_crontab
RETVAL=0
/usr/sbin/apachectl configtest
RETVAL=$?
if [ $RETVAL -ne  0 ]; then
   echo "Configuration file invalid"
   exit 1
fi
/sbin/service httpd restart 
RETVAL=$?
if [ $RETVAL -ne  0 ]; then
   echo "Restart Failed"
   exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Thanks @HBruijn, you saved my day.. nice snippet.. worked for me..